# Matching strings from a list anywhere on webpage's html code including inside tags, comments, etc

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list of string terms e.g. **mylist = ['herring', 'wix.com', 'Solutions']** and I am trying to find if any one of these terms is present inside html code of any of the web sites that I have in a separate list, **including inside of tags, comments, etc.** of the html code.  I am able to use requests and BeautifulSoup to download and parse the web sites but I am struggling with the above task.

The reason I want to do this is because it is not always obvious where exactly and inside of which tags the terms that I am interested in are going to appear on a web site's html code and so I cannot know in advance inside of which tags I should be looking.  Both my string and website lists contain hundreds or thousands of values.

For example, I am trying to find '**herring**' here:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- This is Squarespace. --><!-- herring-minnow-6fef -->
```

or find '**wix.com**' here:

```
<div class="website">
            <a href="https://www.wix.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="logo"></a>
```

or '**Solutions**' here:

```
<u> Marketing Solutions. </u></a>
```

I am able to find all of the above using BeautifulSoup by writing separate lines of code searching inside of each tag or simply searching for a text if it's outside of tags, but I have not been able to figure out if there is a single piece of code or command that I could use to essentially convert the entire html code to text and then search for my terms inside of that one body of text.

Any clues?  Thanks.

Comment: So, how did you load the HTML into BeautifulSoup? If you show that, we can show you how to do what you want.

Comment: Sure.  Here's what I do: 
response = requests.get('https://www.example.com')
page = response.text
soup = bs(page)

Comment: So you have the entire HTML in `page` as a string so you can do `if 'whatever' in page: ...` and `if 'another' in page: ...`. No need to use BeautifulSoup since you do not care where the text appears in the HTML.

Comment: That was easy.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `response = requests.get('example.com')`
> `page = response.text`

So you have the entire HTML in `page` as a string so you can do

`if 'whatever' in page: ...`

and

`if 'another' in page: ....`

No need to use BeautifulSoup since you do not care where the text appears in the HTML.